# JSONata: How to transform result based on if a property is present in input

Tags: jsonata

I am trying to transform the JSON object using JSONata. I want the result object to have a property, "property_3" if input contains "prop3". If the input doesn't contain "prop3" then the result shouldn't have "property_3" as well. Can I achieve this through JSONata and what should be the JSONata expression for this?

Input 1

```
{
  "prop1":"prop1 value1",
  "prop2":"prop2 value1",
  "prop3":"prop3 value1"
}
```

Expected output 1

```
{
  "property_1": "prop1 value1",
  "property_2": "prop2 value1",
  "property_3": "prop3 value1"
}
```

Input 2

```
{
  "prop1":"prop1 value1",
  "prop2":"prop2 value1"
}
```

Expected output 2

```
{
  "property_1": "prop1 value1",
  "property_2": "prop2 value1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve is to iterate over the keys of your input object and replace the `prop` substring:

```
$keys($){
  $replace($, "prop", "property_"): $lookup($$, $)
}
```

Check it out on the Stedi Playground: https://stedi.link/ypXCQNH